# Сегменты данных (памяти) с++

Tags: c++, терминология

Недавно услышал про существование сегментов данных, попытался найти какую-либо информацию в интернете, но не смог, может я что-то путаю. В общем стало очень интересно, что это такое и для чего используется, не могли бы вы рассказать про эти сегменты?

Comment: Этот термин зависит от контекста. В контексте архитектуры x86 имеется в виду память, адресуемая через регистр DS + смещение. В контексте исполняемого кода в *nix это часть памяти программы (после линковки), где расположены инициализированные статики (в т.ч. глобальные). Традиционно в \*nix программа в памяти состояла из 6-ти секций -- .text -- код программы, .rodata -- константы, .data -- инициализированные статические переменные, .bss -- неинициализированные статики (прописываются нулями), .heap -- динамическая память (malloc берет оттуда) и .stack

Comment: Часто сегментами называют страницы. [Страничная память](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Страничная_память)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Модель сегментированной памяти разбивает системную память на группы независимых сегментов, на которые указывают указатели, расположенные в регистрах сегментов. Каждый сегмент используется для хранения данных определенного типа. Один сегмент будет отвечать за исходный код *(text)*. Есть сегмент данных. Здесь хранятся глобальные переменные и BSS(неинициализированные переменные), куча(*heap)*, а также статики.

Также есть сегмент стека. Это Ваша память которой соответствует автоматические переменные.  Так повелось еще з давних времен, что стек растет сверху вниз, а хип снизу вверх. Если интересно - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035568/why-do-stacks-typically-grow-downwards.

[image: Сегмент данных -]

Comment: Как насчет идет вместо ссылки на хищнический сайт с машинным переводоом enSO сослааться на оригинал - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035568/why-do-stacks-typically-grow-downwards

Comment: отлично, заменил